# Handling Singular Resource in REST

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

i have a case where i am actually using some resources that are singular in nature. This is about buildings, so in a city i have a single sawmill and a single town_center.

Now, i am creating everything in a RESTful manner using resources(with :except or :only) where needed. In this case though, i am having a town_center_controller and a sawmill_controller that just have a different show action(they have no other actions).

One can say that a buildings_controller sounds better, but in that case, i would have a single show action to display totally different views(like the one for the sawmill and the town_center). They have many differences and i don't really see how i could stack them in a single controller. However, when i destroy or create a building, i do use the buildings_controller.

I would like to ask you, how would you go about it ? How would you design your controllers ? Would you do what i do and create building based controllers(one controller per each building), or something else ?

Answer (score 1):

I would create a general controller that has the generic functions to support all building cases, like destroy/create/edit, then I would create new controller that inherits from that base controller. This way I will keep my generic functions DRY, and my specific (overridden) functions separate.

Comment: ah, i see, inherited controllers right ? i've watched a railscast at some point. You're right, this sounds very interesting, i will take a close look.